# Linking `Firebase` table's rows with more than 1 activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie in `android studio`.In my app there are many `activities` which have the same kind of information like an image and various text spaces.I have cluttered to much in my app and hence can't use `listview` or `recyclerview` due to time constraints.
E.g 1)`Activity 7201` contains details system,cost,partners etc of `project 7201`.
    2)`Activity 8201` contains details system,cost,partners etc of `project 8201` and so on.
I want to create this fields in my `database` and it should link to that particular activity.

I read some similar answers but they weren't quite helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class containing `system,cost and partners` and push data to firebase under each project . SO the firebase database will look like:

```
-Projects
    -project 7201
        -system
        -cost
        -partners
    -project 8201
        -system
        -cost
        -partners
    .
    .
    .
```

and then you can listen to -project 7201 in activity 7201 and update the UI.

note: you can get data of a specific project like:

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
 // ...
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Projects");
 mDatabase.child("project 7201").addValueEventListener(); etc...
```

in that way you dont need to parse all the projects to find your desired one.

Comment: Forgive me for my naivety.. But apart from  creating new the parameters,do I have to add or maybe edit some other class??

Comment: I dont get you. please explain